# AWS Step Function: no permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have tried to create HelloWorld Step function. But received
is not authorized to perform: states:CreateStateMachine

User is not authorized to perform: states:CreateStateMachine  because no identity-based policy allows the states:CreateStateMachine action

How to fix  it?

Comment: you need to add identity-based policy in your role : states:CreateStateMachine

Answer (score 1):

Your IAM user/role that you are using to create the state machine is missing `states:CreateStateMachine` permissions. You have to updated it, with, e.g. [inline policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#inline-policies) of the following form:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "states:CreateStateMachine",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```